# MethodNotAllowedHttpException appearing and I've tried everything

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying check the access control of /post/10/delete but it keeps on giving this error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

THIS IS MY VIEW

```
@section('content')

<div>
<h1>{{$posts->title}}</h1>
<h3>{!!$posts->body!!}</h3>
<hr>
<small>created on {{$posts->created_at}}</small>
<hr>
@if(!Auth::guest())
    @if(Auth::user()->id==$posts->user_id)
<a href="/post/{{$posts->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
<hr>
<form method="POST" action="{{$posts->id}}/delete">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Delete Post</button>
</form>
    @endif
@endif

</div>

@endsection
```

THIS IS THE ROUTE

```
Route::get('/services','PagesController@services');
Route::get('/about','PagesController@about');


Route::post('/save','PostsController@store');

Route::post('/post/{id}/update', 'PostsController@update');

Route::post('/post/{id}/delete', 'PostsController@destroy');

Route::resource('post','PostsController');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

AND THIS IS THE POSTSCONTROLLER

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        if(auth()->user()->id !== $post->user_id)
         {  return redirect('/post')->with('error','Unauthorized Access');}

        $post->delete();
        return redirect('/post')->with('success','Post Deleted');
        //
    }
```

it keeps on giving an error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" when I insert the link /post/5/delete

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to `http://yoursite/post/10/delete`? Cause that's a `GET` request, but you've defined it as a `POST` route. Also, `action="{{$posts->id}}/delete"` your missing `/post`, should be `action="/post/{{$posts->id}}/delete"`. You did it right on `href="/post/{{$posts->id}}/edit"`...

Comment: I have rectified the `/post`, should i change the method of form to get and then change the get in route to post as well? sorry for the dumb questions I'm learning laravel

Comment: No, leave the route as `POST`, but **don't try to navigate to `/post/{id}/delete` manually**; if you have a route for `/post/{id}` that shows the post, have a `<form>` element on that page with the action `/post/{id}/delete` and method `POST` and you should be fine.

Comment: I tried changing both the `POST` to `GET` .... and it seems to work perfectly fine. Would it cause any other issues???

Comment: You don't want to have a method that deletes things as a `GET` request, otherwise anyone can click on a link to delete a record; opens yourself to security vulnerabilities/users with malicious intent, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having an incorrect URL

```html
<form method="POST" action="/post/{{$posts->id}}/delete">
     @csrf
     @method('DELETE')
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Delete Post</button>
</form>
```

Also either remove this line from your routes or the other lines related to `PostsController` because they're being duplicated 
Run `php artisan route:list` to check for yourself

```php
Route::resource('post','PostsController'); // <--- Delete this
```

Now if you chose to delete this one line instead change your route accordingly

```php
Route::delete('/post/{id}/delete', 'PostsController@destroy');
```

`@method('DELETE')` in the blade file instruct the form to send a request with the `DELETE` method signature which is a RESTful API HTTP request convention when dealing with resources
[Learn More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

### EDIT:

The `Route::resource` alone generates **RESOURCEFUL** routes for you including almost everything you need

Here's an example

`routes/web.php`

```php
<?php
Route::resource('post', 'PostsController');
```

Run `php artisan route:list -c`
`Output`

```
+-----------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Method    | URI                           | Action                                                        |
+-----------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| GET|HEAD  | post                          | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index                    |
| POST      | post                          | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store                    |
| GET|HEAD  | post/create                   | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create                   |
| GET|HEAD  | post/{post}                   | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@show                     |
| PUT|PATCH | post/{post}                   | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@update                   |
| DELETE    | post/{post}                   | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@destroy                  |
| GET|HEAD  | post/{post}/edit              | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@edit                     |
+-----------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You get yourself named generated urls with method signature with 1 line

Comment: Uhh! lemme make a full example

Comment: @AanifZiaTaimuri you're duplicating your routes by calling `resource` check my updated answer

Comment: If you add the DELETE method and explain why I'll delete my answer and upvote yours. Let's make one good answer

Comment: I'm using `Route::resource('post','PostsController');` for show and index functions, is there any way I can use `Route::resource('post','PostsController');` to access destroy?

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb questions, I'm trying to learn laravel using Youtube tutorials...and I'm stuck....

Comment: @CaddyDZ I tried `php artisan route:list -c` it says "-c" does not exist...

Comment: and `@method('DELETE')` is not being accessed, it gets printed as it is on the page.

Comment: Use this: `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">`, that depends on your laravel version, if you don't specify that we think that is the latest.

Comment: Thank you so much @dparoli  it's working perfectly now

Comment: Thank you @CaddyDZ